# scrapy output function directly to google drive

Tags: python, scrapy, google-drive-api

I have a scrapy code which I want its output directly to my Google drive,I have found `pydrive` easy to use and upload files (I tested it and it works)

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file2 = drive.CreateFile()
file2.SetContentFile('testing1.csv')
file2.Upload()
```

How can I use it with `scrapy runspider test1.py -o test.csv` to directly upload to drive?

If it doesn't work, is there any suggestion for doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write custom [pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) or a [feed exporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=exporter#feed-exporters).

For example if you crawler is small and results can fit into your memory than a simple pipeline like this would do:

```
# myproject/pipelines.py

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

class GdrivePipeline:
    data = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data.append(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        gauth = GoogleAuth()
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

        drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

        file2 = drive.CreateFile()
        # write self.data to file
        file2.Upload()
```

Then activate it in your settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.GdrivePipeline': 999,
}
```

Comment: is this affected by concurrent requests,or does it upload when writing to file is completed?

Comment: This pipeline will crawl data into memory and when crawl is finished it will upload it all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that, here is how to run scrapy spider without
`scrapy runspider test1.py`,
You should create a list of your dictionaries then write them to a CSV file, then use your Google function to upload then if you want you can delete the file you created.

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
#Your Spider

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(NAME_OF_YOUR_SPIDER)
    spider = next(iter(process.crawlers)).spider
    process.start()
    #write to csv
    #upload to Google drive
```

Comment: I'm not sure this work, isn't the filesystem used by google functions read only? Therefore your write to csv -> upload to google drive wouldn't work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @foebu you can use `pydrive` to upload